# How to add print button in user detail page in Strapi Dashboard

Tags: node.js, strapi, koa

I have list of users in **Strapi**

[image]

now I wanna to **print** pdf every **user** detail .

for that I think I some **Print Button** must be placed in the user detail

like this

[image]

and when click on it , it will print user detail in a good format .

I wanna to know ,Is that possible ??